# Good approximations for $\int_{-\infty}^0 \bigg(\tanh(ax+b)\tanh(cx+d) - 1\bigg)~\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I have an integral

$$I(a,b,c,d) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \bigg(\tanh(ax+b)\tanh(cx+d) - 1\bigg)~\mathrm{d}x$$

which I need to approximate analytically (to use it in further steps within a machine learning approach) with $a,c\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $b,d\in\mathbb{R}$. What would be the best approach to obtain an anaytic expression approximating $I(a,b,c,d)$?

Comment: What are the limits, if any, on $a,b,c,d$?  I ask because for a number of combinations the integral won't be defined at all (e.g. $(a,b,c,d) = (-1,0,1,0)$ or $(0,1,0,1)$).

Comment: Good point! $b,d$ can be arbitrary but $a,c>0$...I have added this!

Comment: What convergence speed are you looking for? Since normally substitution and series expansion will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For $a=c$, I get an answer

$$I(a,b,c,d) = -\frac{1}{a}(\coth(d - b) (d + \log(\cosh(d)) + \log(1 - \tanh(b))))$$

unless I screwed up? I used the definition of $\tanh(\cdot)$, rewrote it in terms of $p=\exp(ax)$ and did partial fraction decomposition.